# What is a good word to describe a large geographical area

Tags: meaning, word-choice, geography

What is a good word (or a phrase) to describe a large, extensive geographical area, spanning several regions?

I am not looking to use this in a particular context, but to help in conceptualizing a product name.

Comment: Is it possible to get a sample sentence or context where you'd like to use this?

Comment: Should be moved to http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @simchona: Not really looking to use it in a sentence, more of a title/descriptor

Comment: You may want to define what _region_ means in this context. The combination of several regions is usually also considered a region.

Comment: You might call it a *super region*.

Answer (score 2):

'Territory' might do, depending on context. Are we talking about a large area within a single country, or an area that covers several countries?

Comment: single country, but that does not necessarily have to be conveyed directly by the meaning of the word.

Comment: Then, as always, it would depend on context. We might say ‘The territory to the north of the Obugu river is vast and mostly uninhabited.’ On the other hand, we probably wouldn’t say ‘The presidential candidates had to cover a vast territory in their search for every vote.’ In that case we’d probably say they had to cover a vast area. In other words, ‘territory’ is more likely to be found in purely topographically descriptive contexts.

Answer (score 1):

"A large, extensive geographical area, spanning several regions" reminds me of terms like subcontinent [1], landmass, expanse, district, range [2], and the aforementioned territory, except pluralized.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subcontinent : "a large, relatively self-contained landmass forming a subdivision of a continent"

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Range : "a region that makes up the northeastern section of Minnesota"

Answer (score 0):

Well, country comes from Latin "*contrata terra*": the landscape in front of one, the landscape lying opposite to the view.

Terra could be used as a product name.

Comment: That would probably keep the lawyers busy at least.